# primary router-outlet inside ngFor not working for the first element

Tags: angular

I used router outlet inside ngFor, while navigation the url changes but the content is not changed for the first element in loop.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of dataArr">
 <button (click)="item.panelOpenState = !item.panelOpenState">View</button>
 <mat-expansion-panel>
  <button routerLink="tab1" routerLinkActive="active">
   tab1
  </button>
  <button routerLink="tab2" routerLinkActive="active">
   tab 2
  </button>
  <button routerLink="tab3" routerLinkActive="active">
   tab 3
  </button>
  <div *ngIf="item.panelOpenState">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div> 
 </mat-expansion-panel>
</div>

var dataArr = [{pId:1,version:1,panelOpenState:false}, 
               {wId:1,status:1,panelOpenState:false}]
```

Comment: can you show your ```dataArr``` ?

Comment: @capc0 i added the dataArr